# Syslog entries in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, td-agent

When using the command

```
db["my_collectionName"].find()
```

in the mongo shell, my queries return:

```
"message" : "Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/log/syslog".
```

How do I go about solving this permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper permissions for `/data/db` folder/directory.

Comment: thanks for your response. Per your response I tried the command: sudo chmod 0755 /data/db && sudo chown $USER /data/db
and my permission is still denied

Comment: You have to do it recursively:  sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db

Comment: Have you checked the log file /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log ?

Comment: Kormiagin I did as you suggested i.e.,sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db ...here is a snippet of the log file:

Comment: 018-07-12T13:03:24.763+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:17481 #8 (2 connections now open)
2018-07-12T13:12:39.358+0200 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:17492 #9 (3 connections now open)
2018-07-12T13:12:39.361+0200 I NETWORK  [conn9] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:17492 conn9: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.0.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64" } }

Comment: Problem solved using: chmod 775 /var/log/syslog    usermod -a -G adm td-agent...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db
```

Check all paths in mongodb config (/etc/mongod.conf) and assign right permission (dbpath, logpath...)

Comment: Problem solved using: chmod 775 /var/log/syslog    usermod -a -G adm td-agent...Thanks